# Is there a way to open multiple/all notebooks for onenote?

Tags: onenote

When using onenote, it is really painful that I have to open the notebooks one by one, so is there a way to open multiple/all notebooks at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You can open multiple instances of OneNote with shift click on the taskbar icon and have it opened in multiple instances